# No python module found on Mac OSX

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, firebase

I have installed a python module called [python-firebase](https://github.com/ozgur/python-firebase) and I installed pip on my Mac OSX 10.8.5 using the command `sudo pip install python-firebase` and when i run `pip list` I can see it displayed as python-firebase(1.2) but when I run my python script I get

`ImportError: no module named firebase`

I think this is related to python paths but after reading about python module installations I am non the wiser in where I should look...

I am developing my python at ~/Documents/Development/ProjectX and it says it installed the python-firebase at /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/firebase/*

When I run `python` on the terminal and enter `from firebase import firebase' I don't get the module not found error. So it seems in the emulator it works but within my python script it can't find it...

Anyone with any ideas?

Comment: You almost certainly have two copies of Python 2.7, the one pre-installed by Apple, and another one you've installed yourself. And you're using a `pip` for the second Python, but then trying to run your code with the first one.

Comment: So, the first question is: Do you need that second copy of Python 2.7 in the first place? If so, you're going to have to learn a lot about Python installations and where you should look before you'll be able to manage with both of them. If not, you can solve the problem by just uninstalling the extra one and using Apple's pre-installed Python.

Comment: How can I clean it up so I use one? What is the best setup to have?

Comment: How did you install the second one? Homebrew? python.org installer? ActiveState? Enthought? Manual build from source?

Comment: I installed it via Homebrew

Comment: Anyway, the "best setup" depends on what you want to do. If you forced me to pick a "best", I'd say leave Apple's Python as the only 2.x, don't use it at all, install the latest 3.x from python.org, and learn 3.x instead of 2.x. But if you're, e.g., building an app that will be deployed on a server that only has Python 2.7.6 and want to be able to create a movable virtualenv, obviously the best thing is completely different… The question is: Why did you install a Homebrew Python 2.7? If you have a good reason, you have a good reason…

Comment: That's easy: `brew unlink python` will get it completely out of the way, without actually deleting anything (so if you change your mind later, you can just `brew link python` to get it back).

Comment: This could also happen if you have only 1 python implementation but somehow your PYTHONPATH environmental variable is not set properly.

Comment: I unlinked homebrew python but still get the error. How do you check the PYTHONPATH?

Comment: @DeucePie: The reason you still have the error is that you never installed the package for Apple's Python, only for the Homebrew Python. Just reinstall it. See my answer for details.

Comment: @aaragon: That's not impossible, but much less likely. None of the standard ways of installing Python on the Mac touch `PYTHONPATH`, and a user who's never heard of it won't have touched it himself. But meanwhile, thousands of Mac users end up with two copies of Python 2.7 because there are all kinds of old docs lying around the internet telling people to install it themselves because Apple used to only give you 2.5, and with a broken stdlib, even though Apple started shipping 2.7 three versions ago…

Comment: I don't know if the 2.7 version is any different, but yesterday I installed 3.4 in my Mac and the installer adds a file to your home directory with the PYTHONPATH set to the installed directory. Check in your terminal with `printenv` if the variable exists at all.

Comment: @aaragon: I have 4 different 3.4/3.5 installations (one Homebrew, one Python.org installer, two local builds) and none of them tried to modify my (empty) `PYTHONPATH`; there's nothing in my .bash_profile, my Environment.plist, or anywhere else in my home directory. They did of course want to add their bin directories to my `PATH`, but that's a completely different thing.

Comment: Actually, I just double checked my installation and the installer didn't modify the `PYTHONPATH`, only the `PATH` variable, so you may have a problem of conflicting implementations after all. You can have many overlapping implementations of Python in your system without conflicting as long as you create a Python environment. Take a look at [virtualenv](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you've installed a Homebrew Python 2.7, you don't actually need it, and you'd rather not deal with having two conflicting copies of Python 2.7 lying around. In that case, here's what you should do:

- `pip --list > packages.txt`. This gets you a list of all the packages you've installed.
- `brew unlink python`.
- `sudo easy_install pip && sudo pip install --upgrade setuptools`.
- Open `packages.txt` in a text editor.
- `sudo pip install [all the packages you want from packages.txt]`.

  - Or just `pip install -r packages.txt` if you want all of them.

You may want to consider setting up `virtualenv`, or a user site-packages directory, so you don't have to keep `sudo`ing everything. Especially if you're used to Homebrew.

Using either `brew unlink` or `brew uninstall` will get the extra Python 2.7 out of the way, so only the pre-installed Apple version is accessible, solving your problem. But with `brew unlink`, it doesn't actually delete anything, so if you change your mind, you can get it back with `brew link python`. (Or, if you're later sure you never want to go back, you can always `brew uninstall python` later.)

Also, in any other situation this is the wrong way to get `pip`, but for the Python versions Apple has distributed with 10.7 through 10.9, it seems to work best. That may change with later versions of `setuptools`.

Finally, one last pitch: Do you actually need Python 2.7 instead of 3.x? There are all kinds of reasons the answer may be "yes", but if not, you can install a Homebrew 3.4 alongside the Apple 2.7 and they won't conflict at all; you'll get separate programs named `python3`, `python3-config`, `pip3`, `ipython3`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am making a real simple app using firebase so I could use 3.x and I may look into that via Homebrew since you mention that they all have seperate programs. At the moment it has found the module so my code is running now. Thanks again!

Comment: sudo pip install -r packages.txt (if you want all the packages)

Comment: @ManicDee: Thanks. I wasn't sure if `pip --list` output a format that `install -r` could use. (I know it didn't back when it was added in 1.2 or so, and that was listed as a bug to be fixed, but I never tested it…)

Comment: This not only fixed the problem I was having with importing `python-firebase`, but also a dependency issue I ran into a couple months ago with something else. Thank you so much for this very informative answer.

Comment: `brew unlink python` worked for me.